# getting better results with sklearn's Kmeans

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

i've got a 3d space containing three clusters, but when I perform a clustering with Sklearn.cluster Kmeans, the results arn't so good. here is the code and results. hope you can help :)

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

km = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
y_predicted = km.fit_predict(df1[['x','y','z']])
y_predicted

def create_3d_scatter_wprd(df):

   fig = plt.figure(figsize=(48, 24))
   ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
   ax.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], df['z'], c=y_predicted)
   plt.show()

create_3d_scatter_wprd(df)
```

and here are the results of the clustering:
[image]

and for those interested in how the data was made, here is the code

```
space = np.zeros((100,100,100))

def distance(a,b,c,i,j,k,r):
    if math.dist((a,b,c),(i,j,k)) <= r:
        return True
    else:
        return False

for i in range(1,31):
    for j in range(1,31):
        for k in range(1,31):
            space[i,j,k] = 1
            
for i in range(60,85):
    for j in range(60,85):
        for k in range(60,85):
            space[i,j,k] = 2
            
for i in range(35,55):
    for j in range(35,55):
        for k in range(35,55):
            if distance(i,j,k,45,45,45,10):
                space[i,j,k] = 3
```

Comment: How to reproduce `df1`?

Comment: @Corralien df1 is just a simple data frame containing the coordinates of the points x,y,z

Comment: I understand but how to create this dataframe to get a similar plot?

Comment: @Corralien ok I've added the code for the data generation! sorry for the delay! didn't catch your comment.

Answer (score -1):

Difficult to reproduce your problem without your data and you will understand why.

```
f = lambda l,h: (np.random.randint(l, h, (30,30,30)) \
                 + np.random.random((30, 30, 30))).reshape(-1, 3)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([f(10, 20), f(20, 30), f(30, 40)]),
                  columns=list('xyz'))

# Your code here
...

create_3d_scatter_wprd(df)
```

[image: kmean xyz]